# Perl, foreach order

Tags: perl, foreach

Does Perl's `foreach` loop operator require that the list items be presented in order?

For example

```
my @a=(1,2,3);

foreach my $item (@a) {
 print $item;
}
```

will always print 1 2 3?

I suspect so, but I can't find it documented.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. It iterates in the list order. as far as it being documented, look at [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops):

> The foreach  loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the variable VAR 
>   to be each element of the list in turn.

"In turn" here means in order.

Comment: Be aware also that the order of keys in a hash is undefined and not ordered. Lists are always ordered in any place they are used.

Comment: not just undefined, but explicitly randomized in recent versions of perl for increased security

Comment: @Eric I'll bite: what's the security concern?

Comment: @Telemachus => see Algorithmic Complexity Attacks in perlsec - http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlsec.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

Some apparent complexity (arrays are in order, but hashes are not--WTF?) comes from the fact that most answers are ignoring the importance of **context**.

Perl variables, functions, operators and subroutines may evaluate to different values depending on context.  Context can either be *scalar* or *list*.

In scalar context, we want only one value.  For example `my $count = @array;` assigns the number of elements in `@array` to `$count`, because assignment to a scalar provides a scalar context.

In list context we are looking for multiple values.  For example, `my @merged = @left, @right;`.  Assignment to an array provides list context, so `@left` and `@right` are expanded into a lists of their elements.  Since lists are flat structures, we have one long list that combines elements from both arrays.  Finally, the list of values is assigned to `@merged`.

The reason that most of the answers gloss over this is that, even though context seems strange at first, 99% of the time context works transparently and does what you'd expect.

The `for` loop provides a list context.  This means that whatever is inside the parenthesis is interpreted in list context.  The resulting list is then iterated over in order.

What this means is that:

- `for (@array) {}` expands the array into list of elements, preserving the order of the array.
- `for (%hash) {}` expands the hash into a random ordered list of key/value pairs.
- `for ( <FILEHANDLE> ) {}` reads all the lines available from the filehandle and presents them in order.
- `for ( some_subroutine() ) {}` evaluates `some_subroutine()` in list context and iterates over the results.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will. Arrays and lists are ordered.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, arrays preserve order, while hashes do not.